# How to escape single curly brace in xi18n Angular5 localization

Tags: kendo-ui, localization, angular-i18n

I have a kendo-dropdown list in which I want to localize the default text. Is there any way to escape the single curly brace required for [defaultItem]?
Already Tried [defaultItem]="{{'{ text: 'Product Line', value: null }'}}" gives Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}})

home.component.html

```
<kendo-dropdownlist id="ddlProductLine" i18n-[defaultItem]="@@productlinedefaultitem" [defaultItem]="{ text: 'Product Line', value: null }"  [data]="productLines" textField="text"
                          valueField="value" [valuePrimitive]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedProductLineId" class="gprListFacets"
                          (selectionChange)="getBrandsFacet($event)">
 </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

messages.en.xlf

```
  <trans-unit id="productlinedefaultitem" datatype="html">
    <source>{ text: 'Product Line', value: null }</source>
    <target>{ text: 'Product Line', value: null }</target>
  </trans-unit>
```

Angular i18n should identify kendo-dropdownlist [defaultItem] and pick a match from translation .xlf file.